# problems in creating new records ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have attempted to use lynda.com video commands and got stuck in different phases. Please help

So I input

```
rails console
```

Then I input the following

```
irb(main):001:0> subject = Subject.create (:name => "Second Subject", :position =>2)
```

But I got this syntax error and I have no clue! Please help

```
SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting ')'
subject = Subject.create (:name => "Second Subject", :position =>2)
                                  ^
(irb):1: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting end-of-input
subject = Subject.create (:name => "Second Subject", :position =>2)
                                                    ^
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0> subject = Subject.create 
Mysql2::Error: Table 'simple_cms_development.subjects' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `subjects`
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'simple_cms_development.subjects' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `subjects`
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:287:in `query'
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:287:in `block in execute'
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:435:in `block in log'
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:430:in `log'
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:287:in `execute'
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:222:in `execute'
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:301:in `execute_and_free'
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:462:in `columns'
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:114:in `block in prepare_default_proc'
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `yield'
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `columns'
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:208:in `columns'
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:249:in `column_defaults'
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:169:in `column_defaults'
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/core.rb:171:in `initialize'
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:36:in `create'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/muhammedz786/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'irb(main):003:0>
```

Comment: Well for one your MySQL subjects table doesn't exist.  Have you ran ```rake db:migrate```?

Comment: No database table exists. Listen to Travis.

Comment: There are two error traces there. 1) Dont have space before parentheses. That will cause and error. 2) No table for the model. This will also cause an error.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put space before the parentheses

```
# Bad
subject = Subject.create (:name => "Second Subject", :position =>2)

# Good
subject = Subject.create(:name => "Second Subject", :position =>2)
```

Comment: See comment on your question. But, you should remove that space before the parentheses, and run the outstanding migrations `bundle exec rake db:migrate`. Then restart the console and try again.

Comment: Or he could just type ```reload!``` into the console and it will work fine without having to restart it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the comma because you closed the quotation and identified the positions.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell this is a result of not having either loaded the database schema or ran all the migrations on your application.

I get this from your stack trace which contains the following:

> > Mysql2::Error: Table 'simple_cms_development.subjects' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `subjects`
> >     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'simple_cms_development.subjects' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `subjects`

This is shown earlier in the stack than the syntax error, which means that it very well could be the underlying root of your problem.  With rails it is best not to assume that the very first thing it tells you is the problem at hand, but to check the stack.